# Application error while launching on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

While launching my application on heroku the following error massage is displayed on the browser :

Application error : An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command `heroku logs --tail`

So i ran the command:  `heroku logs --tail --app <appname>`

Here's the result :

```
2020-11-27T16:42:45.216475+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-11-27T16:42:47.187262+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-11-27T16:42:49.256889+00:00 app[web.1]: > Mybrary@1.0.0 start /app
2020-11-27T16:42:49.256890+00:00 app[web.1]: > server.js
2020-11-27T16:42:49.256890+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-27T16:42:49.262067+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: server.js: not found
2020-11-27T16:42:49.269182+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-11-27T16:42:49.269460+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2020-11-27T16:42:49.269649+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2020-11-27T16:42:49.269874+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2020-11-27T16:42:49.273359+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Mybrary@1.0.0 start: `server.js`
2020-11-27T16:42:49.273489+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2020-11-27T16:42:49.273637+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-11-27T16:42:49.273771+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the Mybrary@1.0.0 start script.
2020-11-27T16:42:49.273901+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-11-27T16:42:49.281840+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-27T16:42:49.282005+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-11-27T16:42:49.282104+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-11-27T16_42_49_274Z-debug.log
2020-11-27T16:42:49.329568+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-11-27T16:42:49.360883+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-11-27T16:42:49.364797+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-11-27T16:42:51.571060+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-11-27T16:42:53.726395+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-27T16:42:53.726404+00:00 app[web.1]: > Mybrary@1.0.0 start /app
2020-11-27T16:42:53.726404+00:00 app[web.1]: > server.js
2020-11-27T16:42:53.726404+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-27T16:42:53.733090+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: server.js: not found
2020-11-27T16:42:53.741866+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-11-27T16:42:53.742180+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2020-11-27T16:42:53.742419+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2020-11-27T16:42:53.742693+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2020-11-27T16:42:53.746954+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Mybrary@1.0.0 start: `server.js`
2020-11-27T16:42:53.747081+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2020-11-27T16:42:53.747252+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-11-27T16:42:53.747433+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the Mybrary@1.0.0 start script.
2020-11-27T16:42:53.747596+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-11-27T16:42:53.752692+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-27T16:42:53.752896+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-11-27T16:42:53.753045+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-11-27T16_42_53_748Z-debug.log
2020-11-27T16:42:53.805811+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-11-27T16:42:53.850278+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-11-27T16:43:13.701792+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=bookshelf-webapp.herokuapp.com request_id=c430f2d7-d6f5-4938-9f7c-5773f693847a fwd="176.160.132.164" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-27T16:43:14.285272+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=bookshelf-webapp.herokuapp.com request_id=75ac8fb2-555b-4b1f-bff7-c8e8cc2368e8 fwd="176.160.132.164" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

[image: Here is my package.json file]

[image: Here is my sever.js file]

[image: tree]

Comment: What does your file tree look like?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights I just uploaded the file tree.

Answer (score 0):

Tried running your package.json
I ran without node or nodemon like this  "start" : "<strike>node</strike> server.js";

and its didn't start ...
so try Updating it to this

```
"scripts": {
   "start":"node server.js",
   "devstart":" nodemon server.js"
 }
```